# How to add data from 2 tables into one using access database in c# wpf

Tags: c#, ms-access, select, database-design, oledb

I'm trying to add data from two tables in database into one table, but i'm having some difficulties with the code. I need to create an option for users to book a train ticket, and their ID and the ticket's ID needs to be displayed in new table (reservations)

Here is and example:

```
User:
ID: 5
Name: Jack
Last Name: Jones

Ticket:
ID: 9
Name: London
```

RESULT

```
Booking table:
BookingId: 1
UserId: 5
BookId: 9
```

This is my code so far

```
try
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = myConnection;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT User.ID, Ticket.ID AS Reservation FROM (User INNER JOIN Ticket ON User.ID = Ticket.ID)";
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Reservation(ID_user, ID_ticket)" + "values(@User.ID, @Ticket.ID)";
    myConnection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Ticket added");
    myConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Please help me out!

Comment: Your first `CommandText` is meaningless. Because your are executing the second one. You try to use parameterized query but your never add values to your `@User.ID` and `@Ticket.ID`.

Comment: @SonerGönül and how do i do that?

Comment: You are showing RESULT as Booking table and in your code you are inserting in Reservation table. Is the data already present in Booking table when you are trying to insert in Reservation table or is it that Booking table and Reservation table are one and the same and that you have made a mistake while typing it?

Comment: @samar i did not make a mistake. Those are not even actual table names, i just gave an example. The names in the code are right though.

Comment: Then I request you to please give actual requirement rather than giving something different in example and something completely different in a code snippet. I am still not able to understand what is it that you exactly need.

Comment: @samar i've already solved a problem. thank you anyway.soory for poorly asked question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Booking table and Reservation table is one and the same. If not then comment here.

If I understand your business correctly, first and foremost thing is you **cannot** have a join on User table and Ticket table based on their id. They are independent tables and do not have a relationship between them.

Secondly both the data i.e. userid and ticketid should be available on the UI when the user finally books the ticket.

As for userid, if you have an asp.net application, the userid will be available when s/he logs on to your website, else if it is a windows application you can save it in a public static class variable.

The ticketid will be the record the user selects when it adds the details of his/her journey.

You need to pick them and add it in the reservations table.

Hope this gives you some direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT User.ID, Ticket.ID AS Reservation FROM (User INNER JOIN Ticket ON User.ID = Ticket.ID)
```

here on condition is wrong how would userid and ticketid equal?

Comment: i tried to make a query but i guess i just don't understand it and cannot make it right